# Where is the Spline abstract class in Android API?

Tags: android, spline

I found a Spline implementation of Android API of 2012:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Spline.java

But i can not

```
import android.util.Spline
```

into my android project for the SDK 29.

Is it refactored and moved to some where else? Where is the current package containing the Spline Abstract class and the LinearSpline statical class now in Android SDK 29?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it refactored and moved to some where else?

No.

> Where is the current package containing the Spline Abstract class and the LinearSpline statical class now in Android SDK 29?

They are not part of the Android SDK. `Spline` is marked with `@hide`, meaning it is part of the framework implementation but is not part of the SDK.